# Influx DB: Flux Query to return only incremental values?

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I've a dataset with somewhat of "forever" increasing numbers, but sometimes x >= x+1. How would you create a flux query that only return values that are incrementals
if Value x < Value x+1 keep the datapoint, otherwise ditch it.

Here is my base query:

```
from(bucket:"main")
|> range(start:v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "AnalogChannels")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["channelName"] == "RandoAna1")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
|> yield()
```

Thank you for your help